# How can we use Exclusive or in the following situation?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, bigdata

We have a `table` named as `World` having `population`,`area` and `names` of the countries

Show the **countries** that are big by **area** (more than 3 million) or big by **population** (more than 250 million) but not both. Show name, population and area.

- **Australia** has a big area but a small population, it should be
  included.
- **Indonesia** has a big population but a small area, it should    be
  included.
- **China** has a big population and big area, it should be    excluded.
- **United Kingdom** has a small population and a small area, it    should
  be excluded.

I was using the following query:

```
select name,population,area from world where area>3000000 or population>25000000 not in (population>25000000 and area>3000000);
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using sqlzoo.net, an sql learning website which provides its own compiler just like w3schools

Answer (score 2):

please use below query for the solution of this issue.

```
SELECT name,population,area from world
WHERE (area>3000000 AND population<250000000 ) OR (population>250000000 AND area<3000000);
```

Comment: @zia do you know how many zeros are there in 250 million? It should be `250000000` instead of `25000000`.

Comment: @zia ,please check now i have corrected it , please let me know if still any issue

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,
    population,
    area
from world
where (
    area > 3000000 
    or population > 25000000
    )
    AND not  (
        population > 25000000
        and area > 3000000
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query:

```
select 
 name,population,area 
from 
 world 
where 
 (case when (population>25000000 and area>3000000) then 1
 when (population>25000000 or area>3000000) then 2 
 else 0)=2
```

or

```
select 
    name,population,area 
from 
    world 
where 
    (case when population>25000000 then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when area>3000000 then 1 else 0 end)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

select name,population,area from world where (area>3000000 or population>25000000) AND  not  (population>25000000 and area>3000000);

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
WHERE (population>25000000) != (area>3000000)
```

Explanation:

- `(population>25000000)` is true or false
- true is represented as 1; false is represented as 0

Back to your question:  Yes, `XOR` could be used in place of `!=`.